# Nested list in CSV as jekyll datafile

Tags: csv, google-sheets, yaml, jekyll

I have a nested list, it looks like this in YAML and when used as YAML datafile it works without any problem:

```
---
title: "Vlčí hory"
thumbnail: "/img/vlci-hory/thumb.jpg"
products:
- title: "Rys"
  category: "sešit"
  dimension: "A5"
  binding: "V1"
  lineature: "tečky"
  paper-cover: "250g recykl"
  paper-inside: "80g recykl"
  image1: "/img/vlci-hory/thumb.jpg"
- title: "Sova"
  category: "sešit"
  dimension: "A5"
  binding: "V1"
  lineature: "čisté listy"
  paper-cover: "250g recykl"
  paper-inside: "80g recykl"
  image1: "/img/vlci-hory/thumb.jpg"
- title: "Zubr"
  category: "sešit"
  dimension: "A5"
  binding: "V1"
  lineature: "linky"
  paper-cover: "250g recykl"
  paper-inside: "80g recykl"
  image1: "/img/vlci-hory/thumb.jpg"
```

However, I would like to have it in CSV ([since Jekyll can read CSV](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/)) so my girlfriend can edit it in spreadsheet, thus make it more friendly to her.

**I'm looking for spreadsheet template which can generate CSV file with appropriate interpretation of nested lists for jekyll use**.

Here’s an [editable spreadsheet with some of my tests](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lz5Pccg54nc4WX1cjq0Y1_BUwuce0cAnNKz4WGju5Nk/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: You don't need to move everything to CSV. The products can easily be in CSV format (a table with columns: title, category, etc.) while the main title and thumbnail can remain in a YAML front matter.

Comment: @approxiblue Thank you. I see the point. It can work of course. Unfortunately, this would require to edit two files instead of just one. And because I want to make the whole process as simple as possible (want only the best for my girlfriend!:), i cant be satisfied with this solution. So basically, CSV cannot handle nested lists only by itself, right? Then, I would need some jekyll plugin, which could parse modified CSV (using brackets, for example).